# Bootstrap modal didn't display fix

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm working on a PHP admin management page with CRUD. In this page we want to add a vehicle and to edit data which is present in a SQL record table by using a modal box which contains a form to insert and update data. But I have a problem:

1. The modal box didn't display. But I've tried to substitute it with a pure HTML and CSS modal box that works.
2. The pure modal box works perfectly, but in the edit column of the table only the first row can display an edit modal all, the other row didn't show a modal.

Complete page code:

```php
<?php 
require_once '../inc/function.php';
adac();
require_once '../inc/db.php';
if(!empty($_POST)){
$requ = $pdo->prepare('INSERT INTO `vehicules`(`marques`, `modele`, `annee`, `proprio`, `imma`) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)');
$rl= $requ->execute([$_POST['mq'], $_POST['ml'], $_POST['an'], $_POST['pro'], $_POST['im']]);
if($rl){
    $_SESSION['flash']['success'] = "Informations enregistrées!";
}else{
    $_SESSION['flash']['danger'] = "Echec!"; 
}
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE HTML>

<html>

<head>
<script src="../bootstrap-4.3.1-dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="../js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="../js/popper.min.js"></script>

    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8">
  <title>LeLoux</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="../bootstrap-4.3.1-dist\css\bootstrap.min.css">
<style>
body {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0;
  padding-bottom: 6rem;
  min-height: 100%;
}

html {
  height: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

*,
*:before,
*:after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}
.o{
    margin: 10px;   }
.footer {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  padding: 1rem;
  background-color: light;
  text-align: center;
}
.lk{
    width: 135px;
    height: 40px;
    border: 1.6px solid grey;
    border-radius: 5px;
    margin: 10px;
    display: inline-block;
}
.po{
    width: 34px;
    height: 34px;
    background: transparent;
    float: left;
    margin: 1px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.poa{
    text-align: center;
    margin: 5px;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.nav-item{
    width: 17%;
    text-align: center;
    margin:5px;

}
.bob{
          width: 720px;
}
.mo{
    margin: 5px;
    border: 1px solid transparent;
  width: 1100px;
  height: auto;
}
.fo{
    display: inline-block;
    }
a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: black;
}
a:hover{
    color: grey;
}
.co{
max-height:860px;
height:460px;/*pour IE qui comprend rien, et qui ne reconnait pas min-height, mais qui comprend mal height*/
max-width:1100px;
width:980px;/*pour IE qui comprend rien*/
overflow:auto;/*pour activer les scrollbarres*/
}


/* The Modal (background) */
.modal {
  display: none; /* Hidden by default */
  position: fixed; /* Stay in place */
  z-index: 1; /* Sit on top */
  padding-top: 100px; /* Location of the box */
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%; /* Full width */
  height: 100%; /* Full height */
  overflow: auto; /* Enable scroll if needed */
  background-color: rgb(0,0,0); /* Fallback color */
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4); /* Black w/ opacity */
}

/* Modal Content */
.modal-content {
  background-color: #fefefe;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 20px;
  border: 1px solid #888;
  width: 90%;

}

/* The Close Button */
.close {
  color: #fefefe;
  float: right;
  font-size: 28px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.modal-header{
  background-color: #5e5e90;
  color: #fff;
  margin-top: -20%;
  width: 110%;
  height: 15%;
  padding: 16px;
  margin-left: -19px;
}
.btnq{
  background-color: #5e5e90;
  color: #fff;
}
.btnp{
  background-color:#fff;
  color:#5e5e90;
  border: 2px solid #5e5e90;
  font-weight: bolder;
}
.nu{
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
</style>
</head>
<body class="bg-light">
<!--################## add modal  ###############################-->
<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="eModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Ajouter un vehicule</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
      <form action="" method="POST">
                <table cellspacing="3"cellpadding ="6">
                  <tr>
                    <td><b>Marque</b><br>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control nu" value="" name="mq" id="mq">
                </td>

                    <td><b>Modèle</b><br>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="ml" id="ml">
                      </td>
                  </tr>

                  <tr>
                      <td><b>Année</b><br>
                      <input type="text" class="form-control" name="an" id="an">
                      </td>

                      <td><b>Transmission</b><br>
                      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="">
                        </td>
                    </tr>

                    <tr>
                        <td>
                          <b>N de chassis</b><br>
                          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="">
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <b>Immatriculation</b><br>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="im" id="im">
                          </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><b>Carburant</b><br>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="">
                        </td>

                        <td><b>Couleur</b><br>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="">
                          </td>
                      </tr>

                      <tr>
                          <td>
                            <b>Propriétaire</b><br>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="pro" id="pro" >
                          </td>
                          <td>
                              <b>Contact</b><br>
                              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="">
                            </td>
                      </tr>
                </table>

            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="reset" class="btn btnp" data-dismiss="modal">Annuler</button>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btnq">Enregistrer</button>

            </div>
            </form>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<!--################## edit modal  ###############################-->
<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modifier un vehicule</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
      <form action="" method="POST">
                <table cellspacing="3"cellpadding ="6">
                  <tr>
                    <td><b>Marque</b><br>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control nu" value="" name="mq" id="mq">
                </td>

                    <td><b>Modèle</b><br>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="ml" id="ml">
                      </td>
                  </tr>

                  <tr>
                      <td><b>Année</b><br>
                      <input type="text" class="form-control" name="an" id="an">
                      </td>

                      <td><b>Transmission</b><br>
                      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="">
                        </td>
                    </tr>

                    <tr>
                        <td>
                          <b>N de chassis</b><br>
                          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="">
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <b>Immatriculation</b><br>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="im" id="im">
                          </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><b>Carburant</b><br>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="">
                        </td>

                        <td><b>Couleur</b><br>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="">
                          </td>
                      </tr>

                      <tr>
                          <td>
                            <b>Propriétaire</b><br>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="pro" id="pro" >
                          </td>
                          <td>
                              <b>Contact</b><br>
                              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="">
                            </td>
                      </tr>
                </table>

            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="reset" class="btn btnp" data-dismiss="modal">Annuler</button>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btnq">Enregistrer</button>

            </div>
            </form>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>









 <div class="o"><h3 class="font-weight-bolder">LeLoux</h3>  </div>
  <div class="container bob">
      <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
    <li class="nav-item shadow-sm">
      <a class="nav-link active" data-toggle="tab" href="advehi.php">Vehicules</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item shadow-sm">
      <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="adrepa.php">Reparateurs</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item shadow-sm">
      <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="adinter.php">Interventions</a>
    </li>
     <li class="nav-item shadow-sm">
      <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="adfor.php">Forfaits</a>
    </li>
     <li class="nav-item shadow-sm">
      <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="adfac.php">Facturations</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
  </div>







 <center><div class="tab-content mo">
 <div  class="container shadow tab-pane fade show active "><br>
  <div class="co"> 

      <table class="table">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th scope="col">Marques</th>
              <th scope="col">Modèle</th>
              <th scope="col">Année</th>
              <th scope="col"><div class="dropdown">
          <button class="btn  dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                  <b> Propriétaire</b>
          </button>
          </th>
              <th scope="col">Immatriculation</th>
              <th scope="col"><div class="dropdown">
          <button class="btn  dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                  <img src="../im/settings.png" class="po">
          </button>
        </th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>












          <?php 

$req = $pdo->prepare('SELECT DISTINCT * FROM vehicules');
 $req->execute();
$user = $req->fetchAll();
foreach ($user as $row) { ?>
<?= "<tr><th scope='row'>".$row['marques']."</th><td>".$row['modele']."</td><td>".$row['annee']."</td><td>".$row['proprio']."</td><td>".$row['imma']."</td><td><img src='../im/pencil.png' class='po' id='nie' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#exampleModal'></td></tr>"; ?>         
<?php } ?>
</tbody>
</table>
</div>
</div></center>







   <div class="footer">
      <!-- Button trigger modal -->
<button type="button" class="lk float-left" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#eModal">
<img src="../im/add.png" class="po"> <p class="poa">Ajouter</p>
</button>
  <a href=#><div class="lk float-left"><img src="../im/search.png"  class="po"> <p class="poa">Rechercher</p></div></a>
  <a href="#"><div class="lk float-left"><img src="../im/opera.png" class="po"> <p class="poa">Details</p></div></a>
  <a href="index.php"><div class="lk float-right"><img src="../im/close.png" class="po"> <p class="poa">Fermer</p></div></a>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

pure html css and js modal:

html:

```
<!-- Trigger/Open The Modal -->
<button id="myBtn">Open Modal</button>

<!-- The Modal -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal">

  <!-- Modal content -->
  <div class="modal-content">
    <span class="close">&times;</span>
    <p>Some text in the Modal..</p>
  </div>

</div>
```

css:

```
/* The Modal (background) */
.modal {
  display: none; /* Hidden by default */
  position: fixed; /* Stay in place */
  z-index: 1; /* Sit on top */
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%; /* Full width */
  height: 100%; /* Full height */
  overflow: auto; /* Enable scroll if needed */
  background-color: rgb(0,0,0); /* Fallback color */
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4); /* Black w/ opacity */
}

/* Modal Content/Box */
.modal-content {
  background-color: #fefefe;
  margin: 15% auto; /* 15% from the top and centered */
  padding: 20px;
  border: 1px solid #888;
  width: 80%; /* Could be more or less, depending on screen size */
}

/* The Close Button */
.close {
  color: #aaa;
  float: right;
  font-size: 28px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

js:

```
// Get the modal
var modal = document.getElementById("myModal");

// Get the button that opens the modal
var btn = document.getElementById("myBtn");

// Get the <span> element that closes the modal
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

// When the user clicks on the button, open the modal
btn.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "block";
}

// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
span.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "none";
}

// When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (event.target == modal) {
    modal.style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

Comment: var btn = document.getElementById("myBtn"); This will only fetch one button. So you are only binding the click event of one button. You better assign a class to your buttons and then put the click listener on class.

Comment: So much code ... try to create a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).